# how facebook control elements stays open while navigating

Tags: php, jquery

i was wondering how facebook controls its new slideshow / pircture viewer black box while navigating through images with arrow keys via jquery or what ever technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a div for the slideshow, like the following:

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <a id="previousPicture" class="nextprev" href="javascript:void(0)"> Previous </a>
   <img id="picture" src="photo3.jpg" data-currentPhotoIndex="3" />
   <a id="nextPicture" class="nextprev" href="javascript:void(0)"> Next </a>
</div>
```

Javascript to show next/previous button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  openSliderWithBlackBox(); //We'll explain this function later
  //Bind the next/prev buttons click event
  $(".nextprev").click(function(){
      //Get the current photo index
      var photoIndex = parseInt($("#picture").attr("data-currentPhotoIndex"), 10);
      if(this.id == "prevPicture")
          photoIndex--;
      else
          photoIndex++;
      //Now we get the new photo from the server
      $.ajax({
         url: "loadPicutre.php",
         data: {photoIndex: photoIndex },
         success: function(newImgSrc){  //newImgSrc will contain, for example "photo4.jpg"
             $("#picture").attr("src", newImgSrc); //Change the current photo src
             $("#picture").attr("data-currentPhotoIndex", photoIndex); //Update current photo index
         }
      });
  });
});
```

Server side (asuming php):

```
loadPicture.php
<?php
   $photoIndex = $_GET['photoIndex'];
   $newImgSrc = getPicture($photoIndex); //Here you get the corresponding picture src
   echo $newImgSrc; //Example: "photo4.jpg"
?>
```

With all the code above, you can get the photo depending if you did a next or prev.

Now, how can we show it with a black box?. You can use the [jquery blockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#dialog), so our `openSliderWithBlackBox` js function will be like the following:

```
function openSliderWithBlackBox(){
    $.blockUI({ message: $('#slideshow')}); //This opens the slideshow with black background
}
```

You could also do image preloading, animation, etc, but I gave you the main tips.
Hope this helps. Cheers